# jq get multiple values from different [] at once with jq

Tags: jq

in [] there are many of below blocks, how to extract .title and "value" of  .eye.four.watcher1[].name=="cat" for blocks having "group": "A"?

What I tried already is:

$ jq '. | select(.group=="A") |  .title +" "+.eye.four.watcher1[].name' test.json

"ProfileXXX dog"

"ProfileXXX cat"

"ProfileXXX mouse"

but how to print only the titte and value of the "cat" of the blocks with "group": "A",?

```
{
  "title": "ProfileXXX",
  "pagelen": 10,
  "group": "A",
  "size": 1,
  "eye": {
    "one": "git",
    "two": false,
    "three": "...",
    "four": {
      "watcher1": [
        {
          "name": "dog",
          "value": "aaaa"
        },
        {
          "name": "cat",
          "value": "bbbb"
        },
        {
          "name": "mouse",
          "value": "cccc"
        }
      ],
      "watcher2": {
        "type": "B",
        "href": "2..."
      },
      "watcher3": {
        "type": "C",
        "href": "3..."
      },
      "values": [
        {
          "five": "git",
          "six": false,
          "seven": "...",
          "eight": {
            "watchers": {
              "href": "..."
            },
            "forks": {
              "href": "..."
            },
            "clone": [
              {
                "href": "...",
                "name": "https"
              },
              {
                "href": "...",
                "name": "ssh"
              }
            ],
            "pullrequests": {
              "href": "..."
            }
          },
          "fourteen": false,
          "fiveteen": {
            "username": "...",
            "display_name": "...",
            "uuid": "...",
            "links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "..."
              },
              "html": {
                "href": "..."
              },
              "avatar": {
                "href": "..."
              }
            }
          },
          "updated_on": "...",
          "size": 2328936,
          "is_private": true,
          "uuid": "..."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jq** solution:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.group=="A") | .title +" "+ (.eye.four.watcher1[] | select(.name=="cat")).value' test.json
```

The output:

```
ProfileXXX bbbb
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that uses [variable binding](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...) and [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)):

```
     select(.group == "A")
   | .title as $t
   | .eye.four.watcher1[]
   | select(.name == "cat")
   | "\($t) \(.value)"
```

With this filter in `filter.jq` and the sample data in `test.json`

```
$ jq -Mr -f filter.jq test.json
```

produces

```
ProfileXXX bbbb
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##bVLBbuIwEL33K6JRDyCFaAFptUXqod0f2CMSRchNJolbE7v2GJal@fVNx0mAIOpL7Hkvz@@N5@2jOQJJUggL@GN1LhUul0uIwYgCFVawmP6IobDaG2Y8MeDkPyZPY8ADf4@gq/BvIYkx2mtY5EI55H1pMSBJkjCSa28Dey8oLdFOYbE6QiW2gZHpghk7oXw4CV5Qx2c0FTRAX3kN0a32Dgd4ygvqdXy6aBYupYMJ2DPz2FTO21lwVZ9Z8wHr94U171mtuGst53J3ievk33Nch7vQrT4uyqKkQV4X9r1qL5pr@/5NOVVtQ1dX9fgUtyQyrs3/Hepc2WY3XimLH@yZbm6ou7cgDG577yFUVzgCt9P2cp12Jp1R4rC5Knovs/NByapL4lDlt4lK2qrbqtgJEvbGHSPeZIIw2@hLO7uZm81nvx7mP2OQbmOsZAEukvV45ades8rdZxOFxY4wpVHSDvDjIw/w@I7Ln1HSDn0kXHRPfYXnOQmtSU4zulp3yEkkdIA1wkD2KvAyuqdx9DJK2hEZQ9P814akrlwzmVT8DBNZGU98sGI/0Z748AU)